Как сравнить несколько условий в .gitlab-ci.yml?
Вкратце - есть две ветки, и переменная, задаваемая при старте пайплайна, описывающая два окружения. Пробую реализовать простое логическое сравнение (если (A =- ... и B != ...) или (A != ... и B == ...)), но гитлаб его не отрабатывает, вот код:
rules:
  - if: '($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" && $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT != "dev") || ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "dev" && $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT == "dev")'

При этом более простое сравнение работает без проблем, но не полностью покрывает мои хотелки
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" || $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT == "dev"'

Первый вариант пробовал и без скобок приоритета запускать, результат тот же, сравнение не работает. Что может быть не так?

Попробуйте разбить на несколько правил
rules:
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" && $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT != "dev"'
  - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "dev" && $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT == "dev"'

GitLab будет перебирать правила до первого совпадения, это как раз "ИЛИ"

Да, спасибо, забыл вчера добавить комментарий, такую конструкцию тоже пробовал, в общем сами условия работают, но вот изначально полное условие (в вопросе только его часть) мной сформировано неправильно, сейчас работаю над этим.
